# Pycharm debugger when using multiprocessing pool

Tags: python, macos, pycharm, multiprocessing, conda

My problem is happening with this setup :

- Pycharm 2020.3 pro
- multiprocessing.Pool
- Macbook pro 2020 (M1)
- Conda python 3.8

And most of all, it happens when I use the debugger of pycharm.

It shows 8 times (number of processes) in the console :
`Error loading: /Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd_attach_to_process/attach_x86_64.dylib`

Every processes are executed. Results are correct. I can see them with htop command. So it's only a debugger failure and doesn't really impact code execution (correct me if I am wrong).

This is the kind of code I run :

```
def func(x):
    return x+10


if __name__ == '__main__':
    poo = Pool()
    x = [[i] for i in range(10)]
    res = poo.starmap(func, x)
    print(res)
```

I can ignore for now those massive printing in my console but it's not really convenient. If someone has an idea to get rid of those...

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't understand your problem or to be more exact your **question**, could you clarify it please?

Comment: Sorry about that. What those errors mean and what can I do to remove them ?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error from my pycharm using your code and the import of - `from multiprocessing.pool import Pool`

Comment: Are you on Big Sur with the M1 chip ?

Comment: Big Sur? I'll assume you're referring to Mac because of the M1 chip and then my answer will be no, I'm using windows/mint

Comment: Yes, I'm referring to Big Sur OS with M1 chip.

Answer (score 8):

This sounds like something JetBrains devs will need to work out for the M1 (consider [dropping them a bug report](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/sending-feedback.html)). In the meantime, I suspect you could disable it under the options:

**PyCharm > Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Python Debugger**

and unchecking the box "*Attach to subprocess automatically while debugging*". See [the pertinent docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/debugger-python.html) for reference.

Comment: Mac M1, PyCharm 2022.3.3, that solution worked for me, unlike the modification in `compile_mac.sh` from the other answer.

Answer (score 2):

The solution for that error is modify the file /Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd_attach_to_process/linux_and_mac/compile_mac.sh and replace all code for the next one:

```
g++ -fPIC -D_REENTRANT -std=c++11 -arch arm64 -c -o attach_x86_64.o attach.cpp
g++ -dynamiclib -nostartfiles -arch arm64 -o attach_x86_64.dylib attach_x86_64.o -lc
rm attach_x86_64.o
mv attach_x86_64.dylib ../attach_x86_64.dylib
```

then you can run the sh script, which will replace the `attach_x86_64.dylib`  file.

Note. this change will be lost if you update your pycharm.

Comment: Didn't work for me

```clang: error: no such file or directory: 'attach.cpp'
clang: error: no input files
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'attach_x86_64.o'
```

Comment: Didn't work for me either. It returns the same error as @ArturSiepietowski

Answer (score 1):

I faced this same issue on my Mac M1 16" (2021) only when I updated pycharm for newer version.
If you are facing this issue on Mac M1 laptops. Please head to this location on your laptops

`/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/pydevd_attach_to_process/linux_and_mac/compile_mac.sh`

and add these lines in the `compile_mac.sh` file with the existing lines.

```
g++ -fPIC -D_REENTRANT -std=c++11 -arch arm64 -c -o attach_arm64.o attach.cpp
g++ -dynamiclib -nostartfiles -arch arm64 -o attach_arm64.dylib attach_arm64.o -lc
rm attach_arm64.o
mv attach_arm64.dylib ../attach_arm64.dylib
```

I found this link useful for solving this issue: [youtrack.jetbrains.com](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-48163/Pycharn-debugger-Error-when-using-multiprocessing)

Comment: This answer duplicates another answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The answer is not exactly duplicate as the other answer uses `attach_x86_64.o` and my version uses `attach_arm64.o` and i found it on jet brains forum(link at the bottom of the answer) and thought would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know will it completely work, but I think I found a way to fix this error. First you need to change the name of dynamically loading function `_PyObject_FastCallDict` to `PyObject_VectorcallDict` in a file `/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd/attach_to_process/common/py_utils.hpp`. You should replace string

```
DEFINE_PROC(pyObject_FastCallDict, _PyObject_FastCallDict*, "_PyObject_FastCallDict", 530);
```

on

```
DEFINE_PROC(pyObject_FastCallDict, _PyObject_FastCallDict*, "PyObject_VectorcallDict", 530);
```

Then you should replace the content of file `/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd_attach_to_process/linux_and_mac/compile_mac.sh` to the following:

```
g++ -fPIC -D_REENTRANT -std=c++11 -arch arm64 -c -o attach_x86_64.o attach.cpp
g++ -dynamiclib -nostartfiles -arch arm64 -o attach_x86_64.dylib attach_x86_64.o -lc
rm attach_x86_64.o
mv attach_x86_64.dylib ../attach_x86_64.dylib
```

After script execution `attach_arm64.dylib` successfully works and `pydev` shows no error messages.
I haven't try all cases, but breakpoints in FastApi application works and debugger show threads.